# How to create a 3-d graph in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, 3d, drawing

I want to create a 3d graph

By graph I mean in the sense of nodes and edges. I have an adjacency matrix as well as a coordinate matrix for every node. Eventually I would hope to colour these nodes and edges

The gplot function is 3d. The scatter3 function does not allow for edges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know about any third party libraries, but I would personally go for a custom approach anyway.

You could draw the graphs yourself. For this you could use the [Html 5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp) approach, but this has the limitations of requiring support by the browser.

Or you could create the images on the fly server-side. This is what I would go for. Assuming you have all the information you require to draw the graphs, you can load you page with an `img` tag that points to an MVC Action. While the image is being loaded (and created) you should show a nice loading animation of some sort ([here is a good resource for that](http://www.ajaxload.info/)).

Creating the image on the server-side you can use the Bitmap class and relevant `System.Drawing` methods ([here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/Drawshapestothebitmapinmemory.htm)). In terms of an MVC Action you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetGraph(int id)
{
    byte[] image = CreateGraphImage(id);
    return File(image, "image/png");
}
```

with your html something like:

```
<img src="@(Url.Action("GetGraph"))" />
```

Unfortunately, I cant help you with the drawing side of things, it's been too long since I did any 3D graphics work, and equally as long since I work with graphs and matrices.

Comment: I just want to convert that sample data to graph.. Provide the code to convert in to graph.                                         Month Absence Uniform Homework
August 60 70 50
September 51 61 41
October 49 59 39
November 60 70 50
December 60 70 50